# grab both the right and the left clicks of a user simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

So my problem is this,

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a user right clicks and left clicks simultaneously and commit an action if doing so in jQuery. It seems like the code can only detect one right click or one left click at a time in mouse events.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers, I decided ultimately that feature would be too funky to have for users when I was trying to implement it. Hopefully these answers will be able to help other people too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create variables to hold the state of each mouse button individually and use that to determine whether both buttons are down:

```
window.isLeftMouseDown = false;
window.isRightMouseDown = false;

$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 1)
    window.isLeftMouseDown = true;
  else if (e.which == 3)
    window.isRightMouseDown = true;

  if (window.isLeftMouseDown && window.isRightMouseDown) {
    console.log('both down');
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 1)
    window.isLeftMouseDown = false;
  else if (e.which == 3)
    window.isRightMouseDown = false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j151tpt/

Comment: Are you sure mouseup/mousedown can detect the right mouse click?

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: This was pretty helpful and was working when I implemented it on my canvas image. I went without putting the feature in. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. It uses ES2015.

```
let left = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        left = true;
    } else if (e.button === 2 && left) {
       fireYourFunctionForTwoButtons();
    }
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        left = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on the elapsed time in milliseconds between the two consecutive clicks:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn').data('last-left-click', 0).on('mousedown contextmenu', function (e) {
    var nowTime = Date.now();
    if (e.which == 1) {
      $(this).data('last-left-click', nowTime);
    }
    if (e.which == 3) {
      // if less then 300 milliseconds....
      if ((nowTime - $(this).data('last-left-click')) < 300) {
        console.log('Both left and right clicked in sequence in less then 300 milliseconds!');
      }
      $(this).data('last-left-click', 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```